# PHP JSON object will render on local host but not from remote server

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am creating a really simple mobile app for our local track club.  The app seems to be working fine when I test it on my localhost but when I change the links to point to my remote server and then package the app nothing seems to render.  I am hoping that this is a really easy fix.  Here is a page that I would like to populate using a JSON object into a HTML frame using Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>United Track Club</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- This reference to phonegap.js will allow for code hints as long as the current site has been configured as a mobile application. -->

<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--a name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="runnerListPage">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Runners2</h1></div>
<div data-role="content">

     <ul id="runnerList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
     </ul>

   </div>
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
   <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#searchListPage" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#scheduleListPage" data-icon="grid">Schedule</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Here is the JS that I created to populate the above code.

```
$.getJSON('http://unitedtrack.org/Mobile/TF/getrunnerlist.php', function(data){
var object = data.items,
runnerCount = object.length, 
target = document.getElementById('runnerList'),
i;

if (runnerCount>0){
    for (i =0 ; i< runnerCount; i=i+1){
        var unitrun=object[i],
        EventDt = unitrun.First_Nm,
        MeetNm = unitrun.Last_Nm;
target.innerHTML +='<li><a href="#">'+ EventDt +', ' +MeetNm +' </a></li>';
}
}
else {
    alert('there are no runners');
}
});


target.addEventListener("click",data,false);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does the page that calls `$.getJSON()` also come from "http://unitedtrack.org" or is it on your local machine (or somewhere else)?  If so, that's your problem.

Comment: The page that is being called in the $getJSON() is on the remote server.

Comment: Is this in fact your HTML code? Because you have your script calls all commented. If not, please edit your question so that people won't be confused.

Comment: So many technologies. Can't you narrow down the problem to just one of them?

Comment: I am sorry.  I was cleaning up some of the code when I copied it over.  The script calls are not supposed to be commented out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set proper headers on the page you are querying (e.g. http://unitedtrack.org/Mobile/TF/getrunnerlist.php).

You need to set [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) header. See the link for more informations about cross-origin requests.

Comment: There is also a formatting error in the json file, it should be `"items":` instead of `"items:"`